# Iterating and modifying dataframe using Pandas groupby

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am working with a large array of 1's and need to systematically remove 0's from sections of the array. The large array is comprised of many smaller arrays, for each smaller array I need to replace its upper and lower triangles with 0's systematically. For example we have an array with 5 sub arrays indicated by the index value (all sub-arrays have the same number of columns):

```
     0    1    2
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

I want each group of rows to be modified in its upper and lower triangle such that the resulting matrix is:

```
      0    1    2
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0
3  1.0  0.0  0.0
3  1.0  1.0  0.0
3  0.0  1.0  1.0
3  0.0  0.0  1.0
4  1.0  0.0  0.0
4  1.0  1.0  0.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  0.0  1.0  1.0
4  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

At the moment I am using only numpy to achieve this resulting array, but I think I can speed it up using Pandas grouping. In reality my dataset is very large almost 500,000 rows long. The numpy code is below:

```
import numpy as np

candidateLengths = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
centroidLength =3

smallPaths = [min(l,centroidLength) for l in candidateLengths]

# This is the k_values of zeros to delete. To be used in np.tri
k_vals = list(map(lambda smallPath: centroidLength - (smallPath), smallPaths))
maskArray = np.ones((np.sum(candidateLengths), centroidLength))

startPos = 0
endPos = 0
for canNo, canLen in enumerate(candidateLengths):
    a = np.ones((canLen, centroidLength))
    a *= np.tri(*a.shape, dtype=np.bool, k=k_vals[canNo])
    b = np.fliplr(np.flipud(a))
    c = a*b

    endPos = startPos + canLen

    maskArray[startPos:endPos, :] = c

    startPos = endPos

print(maskArray)
```

When I run this on my real dataset it takes nearly 5-7secs to execute. I think this is down to this massive for loop. How can I use pandas groupings to achieve  a higher speed? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer**

```
def tris(n, m):
    if n < m:
        a = np.tri(m, n, dtype=int).T
    else:
        a = np.tri(n, m, dtype=int)
    return a * a[::-1, ::-1]

idx = np.append(df.index.values, -1)
w = np.append(-1, np.flatnonzero(idx[:-1] != idx[1:]))
c = np.diff(w)
df * np.vstack([tris(n, 3) for n in c])

     0    1    2
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0
3  1.0  0.0  0.0
3  1.0  1.0  0.0
3  0.0  1.0  1.0
3  0.0  0.0  1.0
4  1.0  0.0  0.0
4  1.0  1.0  0.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  0.0  1.0  1.0
4  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

**Old Answer**

I define some helper triangle functions

```
def tris(n, m):
    if n < m:
        a = np.tri(m, n, dtype=int).T
    else:
        a = np.tri(n, m, dtype=int)
    return a * a[::-1, ::-1]

def tris_df(df):
    n, m = df.shape
    return pd.DataFrame(tris(n, m), df.index, df.columns)
```

Then

```
df * df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(tris_df)

     0    1    2
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  1.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  1.0
3  1.0  0.0  0.0
3  1.0  1.0  0.0
3  0.0  1.0  1.0
3  0.0  0.0  1.0
4  1.0  0.0  0.0
4  1.0  1.0  0.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  0.0  1.0  1.0
4  0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Hi @piRSquared thanks, for that. I think that the solution you provided is slow compared to the for loop that I'd written originally. I think under the hood apply goes through much like a for loop. If you try it using candidateLengths = np.random.randint(1,7, size=300000), I find that my code executes in 6 secs. Thanks!

Comment: @user3063482 try that.

Comment: Hi, thanks I timed it and your new function returns in 3.74s whereas mine in  5.34s! That works pretty well. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @user3063482 glad I could help.